# Make 2 Verticies Touch but not Merge

Tags: modeling, vertices, wireframe

I have two vertices in space, and I want their x,y,z coordinates to be exactly the same, to lay right on top of eachother. But I don't want to merge them, just have them sit on the same point in space. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the Snap tool with the snap to vertex otpion enabled?

Comment: Works like a charm, not sure why I didn't think of this at all. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Snap* tool with the snap to vertex otpion enabled (you don't have to enable the *Snap* button itself, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcut):

[image]